# Would monitoring for unusual process execution help identify intrusions on a web server?

Tags: webserver, ids

I have a web server with each web application running as it's own machine level account.

The server only hosts the web applications, no other services, dbs, etc.

Apart from the web server processes, nothing else should execute as these accounts.

I keep thinking that if I triggered an alert should any other process be created under one of these accounts it would be a good indication of suspicious activity.

I understand it wouldn't cover system accounts that run a lot of different processes, but if there was an attempt at privilege escalation from the web app - its likely to run as the web app user.

Is this a good approach? Are there obvious flaws?

Comment: Mentioning the OS of the machine would be helpful for context and to suggest specific solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such an alert could certainly detect some attacks, and also allow to narrow them down to a specific web app. There may be false positives, because web servers may legitimately spawn other processes on demand. One possible real-world example would be external programs for file type conversion. However, such programs should be bundled with the web server or mentioned in the documentation, so the admin can install them.

However, attempts at privilege escalation specifically may be difficult to detect by regular monitoring, because some exploits are basically instant after creating a custom process, so you may miss the process running as the web app user.

If you want to manage which processes are created by the web apps, I suggest to go one step further and use an appropriate Mandatory Access Control. MAC checks every action as soon as it is made, so even very short lived processes are detected reliably. Also, instead of just logging or alerting, MAC can also block the process creation. Therefore, this would be a much more effective protection against privilege escalation. Additionally, you can use MAC to restrict other aspects such as file access.